# Segmentation fault with strtol

Tags: c

Playing with pointers:

```
char a[]=" 0xa this is a343 good";
char* *endptr=NULL;
long int b=0;
b=strtol(a,endptr,0);
b=strtol(*endptr,endptr,0);
```

Why I get segmentation fault in the last line ? `*endptr` is `char *` or ?
If I well understood the behavior of `strtol` here it reads the first integer `10` and then `*endptr` will be pointer to the next space after `0xa`. Am I right ?

Comment: You can't dereference a pointer to NULL as you do: `*endptr`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know that but why it is not working for the code above ?

Comment: @Sabrina `*endptr` is the same as `*NULL` which gives you a segmentation fault.

Comment: Sorry did not mention the content of a really sorry my mistake.

Comment: @4386427: Yes, I just realized that it is the second `strol` that crashes, while the first one just doesn't do what the OP expects it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash has nothing to do with `strtol`. The problem is that you dereference a pointer that has the value `NULL`. That is illegal and causes a crash (seg fault).

Your problem is here:

```
b=strtol(*endptr,endptr,0);
         ^^^^^^^
         Dereference a NULL leads to a crash
```

Your problem is the same as this code:

```
char** endptr=NULL;
char* p = *endptr;  // Crash!!
```

So your problem really has nothing to do with `strtol`.

Regarding `strtol`:

If you want `strtol` to update `*endptr`, you need to pass a value which is **not** `NULL`.

The way to do it, is to make a `char*` variable (note: **not** a `char**`) and pass the *address of** that `char*` to `strtol`.

Like:

```
char a[]=" 0xa this is a343 good";
char* p;   // Notice: just one * as you need a pointer to char
long int b=0;
b=strtol(a, &p,0);
            ^^
            Notice: & (aka address of). So you pass the address of 
                    a pointer to char. Equivalent to char** as expected
                    by strtol
```

Comment: Why should endtpr be NULL if it will be updated after the first strtol ?

Comment: @Sabrina - it will not be updated by the first call. Simply because it is `NULL` so `strtol` will not touch it

Answer (score 0):

In your program endptr = NULL, a
so this line will throw and exception:
b=strtol(*endptr,endptr,0);

Looking at the definition of the function:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

You should not use a double pointer:

Try something like this:

```
char a[] = " 0xa this is a343 good";
char* endptr = NULL;
long int b = 0;
b = strtol(a, &endptr, 16);
b = strtol(endptr, &endptr, 16);
```

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions... The segfault is an example of what the standard deems "undefined behavior".

Comment: Visual C++ will call it an exception, but technically you are correct

Comment: Where is the answer ?

Comment: The Visual C++ debugger is welcome to behave however it wants. But its own particular behavior does not dictate standard terms.

Comment: `endptr Reference to an object of type char* whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value`

Comment: @StoryTeller agreed.

Comment: @Sabrina - when I run the code snipet that I posted I get: endptr = 0x006ff7f8 " this is a343 good"

Comment: 4386427 is saying it will not be touched.

Comment: I changed the base to 16 you put 0

Comment: @Sabrina - Notice that this answer uses `char* endptr` and uses `&endptr` when calling `strtol`. Consequently this code does **not** pass a `NULL` to `strtol` and therefore `strtol` will touch it. This code is very different from your original code.

Comment: so endptr will point to NULL but we used the address of that pointer and not the value which is NULL.

Comment: @Sabrina - Correct. For the code in this answer `endptr` has **the value** `NULL` but when calling `strtol` the code passes the **address of** `endptr` and that is **not** `NULL`. This is a very common pattern when you want a function to change the value of a variable held be the caller. So with this code `strtol` can (and will) change the **value** of `endptr`

Comment: Thanks a lot @4386427